# C - searching for a letter in word

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a function which has two arguments, the word, and a letter to search in the word.

The word is actually an array where each letter is an element of the array, e.g. for the word "word", we have the following:
word = [w, o, r, d].

Therefore I have to compare each element of word[ ] to the letter, and if they match the function should return 1, otherwise 0.
The code is the following:

```
char ltt_srch(char word[], char ltt)//LINE 13
{
    int len, i;
    len = sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(ltt == word[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I call `ltt_srch` in main using this code:

```
if(ltt_srch(word[len], ltt) == 0)//LINE 51
{
    printf("Letter not found.\n");
}
```

but I get one warning and one note, specifically:

`Line 13: [Note] Expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char'`

`Line 51: [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'ltt_srch' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: Most likely you wanted to call ltt_search as ltt_search( word, ltt ) not ltt_srch(word[len], ltt)

Comment: Your function expects an array but you are sending it a `char`. In your `if`, change `word[len]` into just `word`

Comment: You can improve the speed for this function from `O(N)` to `O(logN)` using binary search.

Comment: There is also a bug in the way `ltt_srch` determines the length of the word. In `ltt_srch`, C magically redefines `word` as a `char *` because you cannot pass arrays by value in C. Therefore, `sizeof(word)` will be `sizeof(char *)`, which is probably either 4 or 8 on your platform. If `word` is null-terminated, you can use `len = strlen(word);` to determine it's length. If `word` is not null-terminated, you will have to pass the length as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `word[len]` instead of `word` as your first parameter. If you pass `word[len]` you will pass the character on the index `len` of `word` instead of `word` itself.

For example if `word = "word"` and `len = 2` then `word[len] == 'r'`.

Solution:

`if(ltt_srch(word, ltt) == 0)` instead of `if(ltt_srch(word[len], ltt) == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
len = sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]);
```

is wrong. You cannot use `sizeof` inside a function to get the size of an array passed as an argument like that.

You meant:

```
const size_t len = strlen(word);
```

You need to search for the terminator, to work with general strings in C.

Also you're calling it wrong, this:

```
ltt_srch(word[len], ltt)
```

is subscripting into `word` which will yield a character, but you want to pass the array itself so it should be

```
ltt_srch(word, ltt)
```

Finally, the standard library has this function already, look up [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr):

```
int ltt_srch(const char *word, chr ltt)
{
  return strchr(word, ltt) != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ltt_srch(char word[], char ltt);

int
main(void) {
    char *word = "word";
    char key = 'r';

    if (ltt_srch(word, key)) {
        printf("Letter found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Letter not found.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int
ltt_srch(char word[], char ltt) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(ltt == word[i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```